# monoid action on categorical limits

Tags: category-theory

If $\mathscr D$ is a category and $\mathscr C$ is a complete category, consider a functor $F\colon \mathscr D \to \mathscr C$. Let $\Sigma_F$ be the collection of all functors $\sigma \colon \mathscr D \to \mathscr D$ with the property that $F\circ \sigma = F$ (so $\sigma$ can be thought of as a morphism that leaves the diagram $F$ unchanged). Taking limits, if $A=\varprojlim F$, then one gets a morphism $\sigma_*\colon A\to A$ for each $\sigma \in \Sigma_F$, resulting in an action of the monoid $\Sigma_F$ on $A$. Restricting to invertible $\sigma$ whose inverse also leaves the diagram unaffected gives rise to a group action on $A$. Thus, the functor $\varprojlim \colon \mathscr C^{\mathscr D} \to \mathscr C$ naturally lands in a larger category, namely a category whose objects are $(A,G)$, where $A$ is an object of $\mathscr C$ and $G$ is a monoid (or group) acting on $A$.

Does this observation go by a particular name? any references will be appreciated.